# Add elements to a Yii 1.1 form dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, yii, dynamicform

I was trying to add elements dynamically to a yii 1.1 TbActiveForm. I tried two methods to do this, but fails when it comes to validation. Please see my methods below.

**Method 1 # Clone elements; modify id's**

This is how i create form

```
$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id' => 'form-name',
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'clientOptions' => array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true
    ),
    'action' => $this->createUrl('test/manageusers')
));
```

On clicking on the "Add more" button, this script will duplicate elements

```
$('#add-comp-user').on('click', function(){ 
      // template 
      var html = $('.add-comp-users-wrapper').first().clone();
      // next element index
      var next_index = // find last element's index attribute
      // update element id's
      html.find(':input').each(function(){ 
         // update name 
         // update id

      });
      // insert to DOM
});
```

**Method 2 #Ajax method**
Here, on cliking on "Add more" button, i will render form elements with new id and insert to DOM

Both these methods failed in validation. How can i include a newly added element to Yii validation ?

Comment: Can you post your `form code` i.e form elements ?, your validation binds to $model instance

Comment: This is how i created form elements <div class="span3"> 
                    <?php 
                        echo $form->textFieldRow($model, '[0]pi_firstname',array('class'=>'span8 requireBg', 'index' => 0, 'placeholder'=>'First Name')); 
                    ?>
               </div>

Comment: Open your network tab, and check request `parameter name`, validation will work if and only if field name is correct, check `'[0]pi_firstname`  parameter name( in request ) when you submit in network tab

Comment: edit your question for improvement. Place form code in question.

Comment: instead of this you can use multimodelform extension